# Is this also considered a subquery?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

I know how the following queries work, I'm just confused about the terminology.

Each query begins with mandatory FROM clause and must end with either SELECT or GROUP clause. Between the two clauses we can put any number of optional FROM...LET...WHERE clauses. Subquery is simply a query within a query, which means it too has the same structure:

```
var result = from p1 in artists
             from p3 in (from p2 in p1.albums
                         select new { ID = p2.id, Title = p2.title }) 
             select p3;
```

But unlike the subquery in the above example, the following subquery ( `from p2 in artist.Albums` ) doesn't end with its very own SELECT/GROUP clause, so its structure is different in a sense that it begins with a FROM clause, but doesn't end with SELECT/GROUP clause. So my question is whether the term subquery also applies to `from p2 in artist.Albums`, even though its structure is a bit different?

```
 var result1 = from p1 in artists
               from p2 in p1.Albums
               select new { Artist_id = p1.id, Album_id = p2.id };
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second query, `result1`, there is no subquery, just a query with two `from` clauses.

Behind the scenes, using two `from` clauses in this way will be translated into a `SelectMany` operation:

```
artists.SelectMany( p1      => p1.albums
                   ,(p1,p2) => new { Artist_id = p1.id, Album_id = p2.id })
```

Comment: Yes, but isn't "from p2 in p1.Albums" similar in behavior to a subquery in a sense that for each outer element p1, its entire collection ( p1.Albums) is enumerated?

Comment: Yes, "`p1.albums`" is the same as a subquery expression of "`from p2 in p1.albums select p2`" but it's how the query expressions are composed that determine whether you have a query expression with subquery expressions or one without. If there's only one `select` and no `group by` clauses then it's just one query expression (with possibly multiple `from` clauses). Whether something is considered a _query_ anyway is more subjective, but when it comes to syntax of _query expressions_ it's more well-defined.

Comment: I'm really sorry for taking your time, I will mark it as answered in a day or two regardless of whether you answer this or not. Anyways, what do you mean by "...and no group clauses..."? I would assume if there is only one SELECT or only one GROUP clause in a query, then query only has one query expression without any subqueries?! And if a query Q has a GROUP INTO clause followed by SELECT, then Q is conceptually split into two query expressions ( in other words, Q doesn't have a query expression with a subquery )?!

Comment: I mean that if it only has either just one `select` clause or one `group by` clause (without having any of the other clause) then it's just one query expression, as opposed to having two or more `select` clauses or two `group by` clauses or one of each (which would make it more than one query expression).

Answer (score 2):

No, at the bottom you're doing an implicit join, not a subquery.  A join is where you query both tables at the same time (in the same query).